# Parsing with openpyxl rewriting data

Tags: excel, algorithm, parsing

everyone. I can`t understand how to solve the situation.
I have got a function:

```
def get_values_per_year_by_area(areas):
    area_name = {}
    years = get_years()
    for row in VRP_SHEET.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1, values_only=True):
        for area in areas:
            if row[0] == area:
                area_name[area] = {}
                for val in row[1:]:
                    print(val)                
                for year in years:
                    area_name[area][year] = {}
```

I want to read values from excel-file with using dict for that tamplate:

```
{'area_name0': {1998: val1, 1999: val2, 2000: val3, 2001: val4 ... }, 'area_name1': {1998: 0, 1999: 0, 2000: 0, 2001: 0, 2002: 0, 2003: 0, 2004: 0, 2005: 0, 2006: 0, 2007: 0, 2008: 0, 2009: 0, 2010: 0, 2011: 0, 2012: 0, 2013: 0, 2014: 0, 2015: 0, 2016: 0, 2017: 0, 2018: 0}}.
```

When I try to start a code the values (val1, val2, val3... etc...) from dict is overwriting.

```
{'Белгородская область': {1998: 18245.5, 1999: 18245.5, 2000: 18245.5, 2001: 18245.5, 2002: 18245.5, 2003: 18245.5, 2004: 18245.5, 2005: 18245.5, 2006: 18245.5, 2007: 18245.5, 2008: 18245.5, 2009: 18245.5, 2010: 18245.5, 2011: 18245.5, 2012: 18245.5, 2013: 18245.5, 2014: 18245.5, 2015: 18245.5, 2016: 18245.5, 2017: 18245.5, 2018: 18245.5}
```

Help me please to solve that situation. Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved:

def get_values_per_year_by_area(areas):

```
area_name = {}
years = get_years()

for row in VRP_SHEET.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1, values_only=True):
    for area in areas:
        if row[0] == area:
            area_name[area] = {}
            values = []
            for val in row[1:]:
                values.append(val)
            area_name[area] = dict(zip(years, values))

return area_name
```